# python "object not callable" despite working elsewhere in the same code

Tags: python

I have a class called `cell`:

```
class cell:
def __init__(self, row, column, state):
    self.x = column * 20
    self.y = row * 20
    self.state = state
```

I have a list of `cells` which I create using nested for loops:

```
grid = []
for x in range(20):
    for y in range(20):
        grid.append(cell(x, y, bool(random.getrandbits(1))))
```

I can append cells to this grid by using `cell()` with no issues.

Later on, I have a subroutine called `CalculateNextGrid()` which creates a list of cells and returns it as an output.

```
def CalculateNextGrid(grid):
    output = []
    index = 0
    row = 0
    column = 0

    for cell in grid:
        print(grid)
        neighbors = CountCells(index, grid, 20)
        if cell.state == True:
            if neighbors < 2 or neighbors > 3:
                output.append(cell(row, column, False))
                grid.append(cell(x, y, bool(random.getrandbits(1))))
            else:
            output.append(cell(row, column, True))
        else:
            if neighbors == 3:
                output.append(cell(row, column, True))
            else:
                output.append(cell(row, column, False))
        row += 1
        if row == 20:
            row = 0
            column += 1
    return output
```

When I use output.append() to add cells to the list, python throws a "cell object not callable" error, despite it working in the code earlier on. Why is this?

[image: cell object not callable]

Comment: `for cell in grid` -- you are using the name `cell` for something else. (This is partly the reason you should capitalise class names, e.g. `Cell`)

Comment: Or rename grid to cells. `for c in cells`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
for cell in grid
```

you are using the name `cell` for something else. After that point, it no longer applies to the `cell` class.

You should capitalise your class name, `Cell`, so that it won't conflict with a separate `cell` variable.